# The military uses robots? Or the military use robots?

Tags: word-usage, irregular-plurals

Some comments: I use robots. You use robots. The people use robots. Everybody uses robots. The school uses robots, but schools use robots. So perhaps the military uses robots. I saw a previous thread where the military was thought to refer to the military for the country where you reside perhaps. It is a specific military. But I'm still left with sentences like: the armed forces or military forces use robots. My best guess is it is still singular and therefore the military uses robots.

Comment: Yes, it's singular.

Comment: Depends on which side of the pond your bread is buttered.